Identify this 60s-70s schlock horror movie about giant spiders
I saw this in school a long time ago.
It's in English and colour, no idea of any of the actors though. 
Pretty much all I can remember is that there was a giant spider (about as big as a house) and everyone was scared of it obviously enough. There may have been other spiders but the one main one was the biggie spider.
Various attempts at killing the spider were made but what eventually worked was someone crashed a helicopter into it. 
As with most spiders this was enough to kill it. I recall there was a scene with lots of gooey stuff seen pouring down the side of the spider and then that was it, dead spider.

The Giant Spider Invasion
Here is a very detailed plot summary:

It runs into Dutch’s men, whose guns are useless against the giant
  arachnid. Jenny theorizes that the big spider is a queen bee; if they
  can kill it, the other spiders will be leaderless and rendered
  powerless. Although Jenny and Vance have a helicopter to drop the
  bomb, they have to go to the crater to mark the site with a flare.
  When they arrive there, thousands of spiders are hatching. They wait
  until the giant spider returns then signal the helicopter to drop the
  bomb, killing the giant spider and melting all the spider eggs.
  Afterwards, Jenny asks Vance if a similar invasion could happen again?
  The two look on as smoke rises from the giant spider’s corpse.

And here you can watch the complete movie:
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xxywil_the-giant-spider-invasion_shortfilms
Near the end of the movie, at 1:07:38 the helicopter takes off.

Wow...you know all my memories. I'll check and confirm later, thanks!
